# React Context API: Provider not provide

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I needed to add a language change to the website, I used context api, but when I used Provider to pass the state it did not return anything

LocalSwitch location: src/components/LocalSwitch/LocalSwitch

Home location: src/pages/Home/Home.js

***LocaleSwitch.js***

```
export const Context = React.createContext(require('../../locales/eng.json'))
 class LocaleSwitch extends Component {
   state = {
       locale:{}
   }
   _update = lang =>{
       this.setState({
           locale:require(`../../locales/${lang}.json`),
       }, ()=>{console.log(`${lang}`) })

   }
    render = ()=> { 
        const {Provider} = Context;
        return (
            <Provider value={this.state}>
                <Wrapper>
                    {icons.map(icon=>(
                        <img
                        key={icon}
                            src= {require(`../../assets/${icon}.png`)}
                            alt= {icon}
                            className="locale"
                            onClick={()=> this._update(icon)}
                            />
                        ))}
                </Wrapper>
           </Provider>
          );
    }

}
```

**Home.js**

```
    import {Context} from "../../components/LocaleSwitch/LocaleSwitch";
    class Home extends Component {
        state = {
            locale:{}
        }
        render = ()=> { 
            const {Consumer} = Context;
            return (  
             <Consumer>
                 {({locale})=>(
                    <Wrapper>
                        <Header>
                                <Hero id="hero"/>
                                <HeaderTitle id="title">
                                        {locale.titleP1} <br/> {locale.titleP2}
                                        <p>{locale.subtitle}<br/>{locale.subtitle2}</p> 
                                </HeaderTitle>   
                    </Wrapper>
                  )}
            </Consumer>   
            );
        }

    }
```

Comment: are you getting errors?

Comment: Typical undefined error. 'Cannot read property titleP1 of undefined'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you have a Provider somewhere as a parent for your Consumer in your Home.js. You probably want to wrap the context provider somewhere at the root of your app.

In this case the Home component would have to rendered inside of the LocaleSwitch component.

Try to add the Provider functionality in Home.js and you'll see what I mean.

```
const Locale = React.createContext('english')

class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Locale.Provider>
        <Locale.Consumer>
          {
            // Should print 'english'
            (locale) => {locale}
          }
        </Locale.Consumer>
      </Locale.Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

what you are effectively doing is

```
const Locale = React.createContext('english')

class LocaleSwitch extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Locale.Provider>
        <div>I could be a locale consumer if i wanted to </div>
      </Locale.Provider>
    )
  }
}

class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // I have no provider
    return (
        <Locale.Consumer>
          {
            (locale) => {locale}
          }
        </Locale.Consumer>
    )
  }
}
```